# How can I assign a new column to a slice of a pandas DataFrame with a multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with a multi-index like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr = [1]*3 + [2]*3
arr2 = list(range(3)) + list(range(3))
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
    arr,
    arr2
], names=['one', 'two'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(len(mux))}, mux)
df
```

```
        a
one two 
1   0   0
1   1   1
1   2   2
2   0   3
2   1   4
2   2   5
```

I have a function that takes a slice of a DataFrame and needs to assign a new column to the rows that have been sliced:

```
def work(df):
    b = df.copy()

    #do some work on the slice and create values for a new column of the slice
    b['b'] = b['a']*2

    #assign the new values back to the slice in a new column
    df['b'] = b['b']

#pass in a slice of the df with only records that have the last value for 'two'
work(df.loc[df.index.isin(df.index.get_level_values('two')[-1:], level=1)])
```

However calling the function results in the error:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  # This is added back by InteractiveShellApp.init_path()
```

How can I create a new column 'b' in the original DataFrame and assign its values for only the rows that were passed to the function, leaving the rest of the rows nan?

The desired output is:

```
        a   b
one two 
1   0   0   nan
1   1   1   nan
1   2   2   4
2   0   3   nan
2   1   4   nan
2   2   5   10
```

NOTE: In the work function I'm actually doing a bunch of complex operations involving calling other functions to generate the values for the new column so I don't think this will work. Multiplying by 2 in my example is just for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't have an error, but just a warning. Try this:

```
def work(df):
    b = df.copy()

    #do some work on the slice and create values for a new column of the slice
    b['b'] = b['a']*2

    #assign the new values back to the slice in a new column
    df['b'] = b['b']
    return df

#pass in a slice of the df with only records that have the last value for 'two'
new_df = work(df.loc[df.index.isin(df.index.get_level_values('two')[-1:], level=1)])
```

Then:

```
df.reset_index().merge(new_df, how="left").set_index(["one","two"])
```

Output:

```
          a     b
one two     
1   0      0    NaN
    1      1    NaN
    2      2    4.0
2   0      3    NaN
    1      4    NaN
    2      5    10.0
```

Comment: This was helpful and gives the correct result, thanks! BTW, is their an approach that would be able to do the "merging" within the function itself? Or would that require that I pass the entire DataFrame to the function instead of just the slice?

Comment: Did you look at my answer below that shows how to do it in one line?

Comment: @MikeTomaino he needs to call the function `work()`, see the note in the question.

Comment: @Joe Yes you can do the merging inside the function but then you have to pass the entire dataframe to the function as you said. Please accept my answer if you want ([accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235))

Comment: @DavideBrex... Whoops I missed that. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a separate function at all. Try this...

```
df['b'] = df['a'].where(df.index.isin(df.index.get_level_values('two')[-1:], level=1))*2
```

The `Series.where()` function being called on `df['a']` here should return a series where values are `NaN` for rows that do not result from your query.